# IIS 7 Site binding same port with DNS Server

Tags: iis, networking, dns, iis-7.5, iis-express

I'm new to setting up in IIS 7.
Apparently I have to use port 443 for a site but I cannot bind it since DNS Server is already using port 443.

Is there a way I can use 443 for my site while DNS Server is also using the same port?

Comment: You could do so only if you have two ip addresses, and configure DNS server to use port 443 on one ip address and IIS to use port 443 on the other. But DNS server probably should not be using that port at all, so you should investigate that first.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help :)